# Rewrite C++ code into Objective C

Tags: iphone, c++, url-rewriting, header-files

I got some C++ Sourcecode that I would like to rewrite into Objective C.
It would help me alot if someone could write me a header file for this Code. When I  get the Headerfile I would be able to rewrite the rest of the Sourcecode.

It would be very nice if someone could help me please.

Thanks

I will poste the sourcecode here:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream.h>

#define STATES 5

int transitionTable[STATES][STATES];

// function declarations:
double randfloat                 (void);
int    chooseNextEventFromTable  (int current, int table[STATES][STATES]);
int    chooseNextEventFromTransitionTablee (int currentState);
void   setTable                  (int value, int table[STATES][STATES]);


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main(void) { 
   int i;

   // for demo purposes:
 transitionTable[0][0] = 0;
 transitionTable[0][1] = 20;
 transitionTable[0][2] = 30;
 transitionTable[0][3] = 50;
 transitionTable[0][4] = 0;
 transitionTable[1][0] = 35;
 transitionTable[1][1] = 25;
 transitionTable[1][2] = 20;
 transitionTable[1][3] = 30;
 transitionTable[1][4] = 0;
 transitionTable[2][0] = 70;
 transitionTable[2][1] = 0;
 transitionTable[2][2] = 15;
 transitionTable[2][3] = 0;
 transitionTable[2][4] = 15;
 transitionTable[3][0] = 0;
 transitionTable[3][1] = 25;
 transitionTable[3][2] = 25;
 transitionTable[3][3] = 0;
 transitionTable[3][4] = 50;
 transitionTable[4][0] = 13;
 transitionTable[4][1] = 17;
 transitionTable[4][2] = 22;
 transitionTable[4][3] = 48;
 transitionTable[4][4] = 0;

   int currentState = 0;
 for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
    std::cout << currentState << " ";
      currentState = chooseNextEventFromTransitionTablee(currentState);
   }
   return 0;
};


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


//////////////////////////////
//
// chooseNextEventFromTransitionTable -- choose the next note.
//

int chooseNextEventFromTransitionTablee(int currentState) {
 int targetSum   = 0;
 int sum         = 0;
 int targetNote  = 0;
 int totalevents = 0;
 int i;

 currentState = currentState % STATES;  // remove any octave value
 for (i=0; i<STATES; i++) {
  totalevents += transitionTable[currentState][i];
 }
 targetSum   = (int)(randfloat() * totalevents + 0.5);
 while (targetNote < STATES &&
     sum+transitionTable[currentState][targetNote] < targetSum) {
  sum += transitionTable[currentState][targetNote];
  targetNote++;
 }

 return targetNote;
}





//////////////////////////////
//
// randfloat -- returns a random number between 0.0 and 1.0.
//

double randfloat(void) {
   return (double)rand()/RAND_MAX;
}



//////////////////////////////
//
// setTable -- set all values in the transition table to the given value.
//

void setTable(int value, int table[STATES][STATES]) {
   int i, j;
   for (i=0; i<STATES; i++) {
      for (j=0; j<STATES; j++) {
         table[i][j] = value;
      }
   }
}
```

**Update**

I'm not only compiling the header file there is another file i'm compiling too

SourceCode:

```
//
//  markovThreadsChainsViewController.m
//  markovThreadsChains
//
//  Created by Philippe Mokrzycki on 15.01.11.
//  Copyright 2011 TGM. All rights reserved.
//

#import "markovThreadsChainsViewController.h"
#import "markov.h"
//#import "markovChainOC.h"

@implementation markovThreadsChainsViewController

@synthesize mcValueLabel, threadStartGenerateButton, threadStopGenerateButton;

- (IBAction) startThreadGen:(UIButton *)sender{
    threadStopGenerateButton.hidden=NO;
    threadStartGenerateButton.hidden=YES;
    mcValueLabel.text = @"0";

    currentState=0;

//  markovChainOC *mCobc = [[markovChainOC alloc]init];

//  [mCobc setCurrentState:0];
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(startThreading)  toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}

- (IBAction) stopThreadGen:(UIButton *)sender{
    threadStopGenerateButton.hidden=YES;
    threadStartGenerateButton.hidden=NO;
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(stopThreading) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}

- (void) startThreading {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];

    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(markovGen) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
    [pool release];
}

- (void) stopThreading {
    [NSThread cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
}

- (void)markovGen{
    transitionTable[0][0] = 25;
    transitionTable[0][1] = 25;
    transitionTable[1][0] = 25;
    transitionTable[1][1] = 25;

//  int actualValue = [mCobc getCurrentState];

    int actualValue = currentState;
    mcValueLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%", actualValue];
    currentState = chooseNextEventFromTransitionTablee(currentState);
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(markovGen) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

}


/*
// The designated initializer. Override to perform setup that is required before the view is loaded.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
*/

/*
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView {
}
*/


/*
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
*/


/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [mcValueLabel release];
    [threadStartGenerateButton release];
    [threadStopGenerateButton release];
//  [mCobc release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: Why do you want to rewrite this code in ObjC? You can set the compilation target to "Objective C++" and Xcode will compile C++ code just fine.

Comment: The compiler will accept the c++ code aswell, there is no need to rewrite it in objective C.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, I know that that i can compile it in this form but I need to implement the functions in another programm, and this programm is written in Objective C

Comment: You can use the C++ functions from ObjC(++).

Comment: Just compile your program as Objective-C++ and both Objective-C and C++ syntax will work fine.  In your Objective-C code you can instantiate C++ objects, call their methods, etc., and vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put these lines into a header file, and you should be able to include the header and call the functions from any other Objective-C or C source file.

(To support C++ also, you may need to put `extern "C" { ... }` around them, unless you are compiling everything as C++ or Objective-C++.)

```
#pragma once

#define STATES 5

int transitionTable[STATES][STATES];

// function declarations:
double randfloat                 (void);
int    chooseNextEventFromTable  (int current, int table[STATES][STATES]);
int    chooseNextEventFromTransitionTablee (int currentState);
void   setTable                  (int value, int table[STATES][STATES]);
```

More detail:

To use these functions from another class, you'll need the following files in your project:

- `markov.h` (or whatever you decide to call it), containing the lines above.
- `markov.c` (or whatever you decide to call it), containing the other stuff from your original source file, except for the `main` function, which you should remove

Then, your other files that use the functions should have an `#include "markov.h"` line, and then you should be able to call them.

If you are getting linker errors about missing functions, it means that you are not compiling `markov.c` as part of the project, or there are some options that are causing the function names to not match properly.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me but now i have another problem, when i'm trying to compile my program i get a error message:  

"_chooseNextEventFromTransitionTablee", referenced from:
-[markovThreadsChainsViewController markovGen] in markovThreadsChainsViewController.o
 symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Are you compiling your original file as well? The header by itself is not enough: you have to also compile your original functions, or link to a library containing them.

Comment: I'm compiling not only the header 

I would like to use this functions in another class

Answer (score 3):

This code has nothing object-oriented in it at all. Just change iostream.h to stdio.h, and cout to printf. Then it's a regular C program.